# Как убрать класс из подсказок Resharper'а?

Tags: c#, resharper

Иногда когда я пишу код в реализации репозитория мне Resharper предлагает на выбор одноимённый класс из папки Migration:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли  как-то указать, чтобы из папки миграций исключить классы к предложению подсказок?

Comment: Вообще, конечно, потребность в этом не возникала если бы я не забывал пользоваться Implement missing members – ведь при таком сценарии resharper подтянул бы using c домена.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/06/26/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/ Тут что-то похожее на нужное вам описано

Comment: Как самое простое решение - можете переименовать класс. И по моему скромному мнению странно называть класс Brand в папке миграций. Лучше называть %глагол_действия%_%предмет_действия%. Что-то вроде "CreateUserTable".